# Unable to install Pillow in venv on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I need help fixing this. I have pillow 7.0.0 installed but it is not accessible in my virtual environment. Trying to install using `pip install pillow` in the virtual env throws the error below. Can someone shed some light on how to fix this?

```
Collecting pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.1.0.tar.gz (49.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [156 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
     ...

      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"9.1.0\" -I/tmp/pip-install-dxz6gg5z/pillow_5c0ecf282df741a599c5f2ec14a30181 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/onah/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/_imaging.o
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-dxz6gg5z/pillow_5c0ecf282df741a599c5f2ec14a30181 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/onah/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/_imagingmorph.o
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3.11, by any chance?

Comment: @navneethc Yes, they are: "creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311"